# Python Plotly tips on how to set Z-axis to logscale

Tags: python, plotly

Greetings fellow humans,
What I wish to do is simply plot the 3d surface plots Z-scale (code below) as logarithmic scale. I've been looking at the official documentation for a bit now and I can't seem to find the "fig.update_xaxes(type="log")" equivalent for the Z scale. I've tried simply replacing the 1st 'x' with a 'z', but that resulted in an error:
File "/path/to/file.py", line 18, in 
fig.update_zaxes(type="log")
AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'update_zaxes'

Does anyone perhaps have some advice? The surface plot in 3D looks good, but it would look better in log-scale.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import pandas as pd

z_data = pd.read_csv('data.csv',index_col=False)

y = z_data['1']
z = z_data.iloc[:,1:]

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(z=z, y=y)])
fig.update_layout(title='3D plot', autosize=False,
                  width=1880, height=1080,
                  margin=dict(l=65, r=50, b=65, t=90))
#fig.update_zaxes(type="log")
fig.write_image("data.png")
fig.show()
```

Thank you to anyone trying to help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The axes of the 3D graph can be set using the scene. Since we didn't have any data, we added the log setting for the z-axis from the [official reference example](https://plotly.com/python/3d-surface-plots/#topographical-3d-surface-plot). setting dtick=1, the result will be 1,10,100,100.... For more details, please check [this](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/scene/#layout-scene-zaxis-dtick).

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import pandas as pd

# Read data from a csv
z_data = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/api_docs/mt_bruno_elevation.csv')

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(z=z_data.values)])

fig.update_layout(title='Mt Bruno Elevation', autosize=False,
                  width=500, height=500,
                  margin=dict(l=65, r=50, b=65, t=90))

fig.update_layout(scene=dict(zaxis=dict(dtick=1, type='log')))

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was indeed what I was looking for!

Comment: I know it seems like a lot, but if my answer is helpful, please accept it.

Comment: Hey, sorry for taking so long to accept, I must have somehow missed the "accept" button last time. Thanks again for your help!